# What is std::jthread in c++20?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

1. What advantages does it offer over `std::thread`?
2. Will it deprecate the existing `std::thread`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`std::jthread` is like `std::thread`, only without the stupid. See, `std::thread`'s destructor would terminate the program if you didn't `join` or detach it manually beforehand. This led to tons of bugs, as people would expect it to join on destruction.

`jthread` fixes this; it joins on destruction by default (hence the name: "joining thread"). It also supports a mechanism to ask a thread to halt execution, though there is no enforcement of this (aka: you can't *make* another thread stop executing).

At present, there is no plan to deprecate `std::thread`.

Comment: @Waqar: You could see it that way, but it's not necessarily implemented that way.

Comment: f wonder who's bright idea it was to try to cram in a suspend execution feature. Thst never works. It hasn't worked anywhere in 30 years of threads. Everyone will have to use their own explicit condition variables just as they always have.

Comment: > supports a mechanism to ask a thread to halt execution
I assume you are referring to `stop_source` here, if so how would that look like in code?

Comment: @ZanLynx it *has* an explicit condition variable, which it passes to the function it runs.

Comment: @Waqar you take a `std::stop_token` as the first parameter of your function, and periodically check if `stop_requested` is true

Comment: @NicolBolas So if it automatically joins, then let's say I am building a web server where every request receives a new created thread: If connection to the client terminates or is interrupted then I could simply `return` from that thread routine, and the thread's ressources would automatically be released to OS? And would this behaviour be equivalent to creating an `std::thread` and manually detach it for every client connection?

Comment: @alexpanter no, detaching is sth else, well… detaching. All it means is that jthread is semantically equivalent to this `struct jthread : std::thread { using std::thread::thread; ~jthread() { join(); } };` (stopping omitted on purpose). It means that a. if function in thread returned, thread’s handle can be just destructed b. if it didn’t, the program will block and wait for it upon destruction of the handle (jthread object). In some contexts it may act in a manner similar to detaching but it’s by no means the same.

Comment: @alexpanter note the differences here godbolt.org/z/PKnEcjfjP

Answer (score 1):

Here are the key differences between `std::jthread` and `std::thread`:

1. **Automatic Joining:**

   - In the case of `std::jthread`, the thread is automatically joined when its destructor is called.
   - For `std::thread`, if the thread is still joinable upon destruction, it leads to a call to `std::terminate`, potentially causing errors in applications (not terminating all threads).
   - Using `std::jthread` eliminates the need to explicitly join threads and helps in avoiding issues related to incomplete thread termination.
2. **Enhanced Control with `std::stop_token`:**

   - `std::jthread` provides more control over thread execution through the use of `std::stop_token`.
   - The `std::stop_token` is a mechanism to send a stop request to the thread's execution. It operates as a request, allowing for controlled termination if properly handled within the thread's execution.
   - For further details on `std::stop_token`, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token).

In summary, `std::jthread` simplifies thread management by automatically handling joining during destruction and offers additional control over thread execution using `std::stop_token`.

Answer (score -6):

The standard library provides `std::jthread`, which is a “joining thread” that follows `RAII` by having its destructor `join()`. Joining is done by destructors, so the order is the reverse of construction.
When using `std::jthread` pay attention to RAII semantics.

```
int main() {

    long v {0};
    std::jthread t([&v]() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i++ < 10;)
            v++;
        });
        
    std::cout << v << ' '; // will print 0
}
```

This will print 0 at the output since joining has done at the end of the block (after `std::cout << ...`)

```
int main() {

    long v {0};
        {
            std::jthread t([&v]() {
                for (size_t i = 0; i++ < 10;)
                    v++;

              std::cout << v << ' '; // will print 10
                });
        }
}
```

This will print 10 properly.
As for `std::thread` deprecation, I don't think it happens at least in near future.

Comment: The first example printing 0 depends on the OS's schedule. In a high-load system, the first example might also print 10. Your example is not appropriate.

Comment: This is a data race and UB. Anyone reading this should never do this.